# Removing the line and address from scrlttr

Tags: koma-script, letters

`scrlttr2` seems to set a line with the address on it. I can't figure out *which* of the many `scrlttr2` options turns it off.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Seamus}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Earth\\
  Solar System\\
  Milky Way\\
  The Universe}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{TeX\\
    Stackexhange\\
    dot com\\
    The internet}
  \opening{Dear TeXnicians}

  I am having trouble with the above ruled line

  \closing{Yours hopefully}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: this line!]

I am trying to remove the rule, and the text highlighted...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To remove the line and the text, add `backaddress=off` to the class options. To remove just the line, add `backaddress=plain` to the class options.

Comment: That's great thanks. But this still seems to leave loads of whitespace where the `backaddress` used to be...

Comment: Can you provide a reference? I would like to see what other options are available. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Set the KOMA variable `backaddress` to be empty:

```
\setkomavar{backaddress}{}
```

or see Michael's suggestion.

To remove the reserved space, set the pseudolength `backaddrheight` to 0:

```
\makeatletter
\@setplength{backaddrheight}{0pt}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the back address and the line with a [KOMA option](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf#desc:scrlttr2.variable.backaddress):

```
\KOMAoptions{backaddress=false}
```

(The default value of this option is `underlined` which has the same effect as a true-ish value. Also supported is the value `plain` which just disables the underlining.)

The option setting integrated into your example:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\KOMAoptions{backaddress=false}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Seamus}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Earth\\
  Solar System\\
  Milky Way\\
  The Universe}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{TeX\\
    Stackexhange\\
    dot com\\
    The internet}
  \opening{Dear TeXnicians}

  I am having trouble with the above ruled line

  \closing{Yours hopefully}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's more or less the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Schweinebacke, well, it's more. It includes a working example, it explicitly includes a way how to actually set that option and it includes a reference (link!) to that and related options. Depending on how often you use this package this saves you some reading of the fine Koma manual.